# Directly selecting an item for promotion using SmartTarget

Tags: smarttarget

I'm following the SmartTarget documentation [here (login needed)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion) as I would like to select a published component as the content for a given promotion.

It's a little confusing:

1. The interface shows to enter them in the format 7707,7719 etc (assuming 7707 is really component tcm:2-7707 etc).
2. The documentation wants a 'secondid' based on the id/template id combo eg: `tcm_9-11-1104-16_tcm_9-919-32`

I've used the preview area of SmartTarget to get my secondid values, and I've entered them into the promotion and I'm not getting any results.  I've checked the promo triggers by looking in a specific location.

I've tried combinations of values:

- With tcm id (with / without colon, hypen, type etc)
- Without tcm id (with / without colon, hypen, type etc)
- Secondids
- Both / all at the same time

I'm starting to think it's a bug in the system, or there is something terribly wrong with me!

I'm using ST 2011 SP 3, Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation link in your question is linking to http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion. Typo?

Comment: Do you see the promotion *and* the items in Fredhopper's preview window? Or does it already go wrong there?

Comment: these items are in there.

Comment: So what you are saying is that in Fredhopper's preview, your promotion is firing and the Component Presentations show up. But when retrieved through SmartTarget, neither the Promotion nor the CPs are showing up? In that case, you should check that the correct triggers are being sent and also check if the problem is with rendering the CPs (check CD log files and SiteEdit markup)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your question I understand that you want to set up a promotion which uses a list of hand picked items to return for your promotion.

In the field you need to enter a comma separated list of `secondid` values, in the `tcm_9-1104-16_tcm_9-919-32` format. This format effectively is a reference to a specific component presentation. The fist part of the id is the component id, the second part of the id is the compontent template id.

The Business Manager GUI suggest to enter a list of id's like 7707,7719 since you could have any data as promotional items in the system. The component presentations ids stored in the secondid field are what you are looking for and they happen to be a bit longer than the 7707 example.

In the Business Manager preview you can enable the triggers used by your promotion so you can test what the promotion returns.

**Update**: Also see the documentation [Defining promotion action](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2011_SP3/task_08A4E97C9E214FCA8A154B12A027490C) (login required). Apparently you can also choose to enter a  separated list.

> If you select Handpicked list, enter item IDs, the value of an item's secondid attribute. You can find out the secondid by opening the Preview Page. The format of a content item's secondid is, for example, tcm_9-1104-16_tcm_9-919-32. Add each content item ID on a separate line.

Comment: +1. As another `Handpicked` example we have tcm_69-2781-16_tcm_69-6322-32 in one of our training environments. Is there an extra "11" in your example (after the first tcm_9), Jan?

Comment: Well spotted Alvin. I think the extra 11 is a typo in the manual, copied by John an me. It should be the "tcm_9-1104-16_tcm_9-919-32" format. The id "tcm:9-11-1104-16" would not be a valid TCM id in Tridion. i added a comment in the manual and updated the answer.

Comment: Hi Jan, I'm using the preview to copy my secondid value, this is correct and it still isn't working - check point '2' in my question.  thanks.  I've tested the triggers in the promo manager and it works with components from a location, just never by secondid. thanks

Comment: Is it published and in the right publication? Can you find the item in the business manager?

Comment: @JanH, I only caught the typo because I was just about to post an answer. :-) You're too fast.

Comment: @alvin - yes I've checked it's published in the correct publication, I've only this one that can publish.